# Class availability in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I'd like to mark an entire class as available only for iOS 13+. Is this possible?

I imagine running an availability check before using the class, like this:

```
if (@available(iOS 13, *)) {
    /* Use my special, iOS 13+ only class. */
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Should be possible, just use the availability macros on your own class.  I.e., put in `API_AVAILABLE(ios(13.0))` before the @interface declaration.  Or use the NS_CLASS_AVAILABLE macro the same way Apple does.

Comment: Is that in .h or in .m, or both?

Comment: It should be on the `@interface`, which is normally in the .h, but if you have a private class where even the `@interface` is in the .m , then it would go there too.   It does not need to be on the `@implementation` .